# Asking a priority list from user, then sort list according to that

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a small program, where there are 4 light switches. The lamp only turning on, when 3 switch out of the 4 is up. I'd like to ask the user if there should be a priority, and if yes, what should it be. Lets say the C switch must be up first, then the A, then the B. If the user inputs 1-s (1-switch on, 0-switch off) in that order, the lamp will turn on, otherwise it'll stay turned off. I'm kinda stuck, don't know how could I do that, maybe I'm overcompensating the problem. Thanks.

```
def sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]


A = B = C = D = int()
arr = []

sorrend = input("What should be the switches order: ")
lista = sorrend.split()
print("Switches order: ")
print(lista)


while [A, B, C, D] != 0 or [A, B, C, D] != 1:
    A = int(input("A switch (1-on, 0-off): "))
    B = int(input("B switch  (1-on, 0-off): "))
    C = int(input("C switch  (1-on, 0-off): "))
    D = int(input("D switch  (1-on, 0-off): "))
    if 1 in (A, B, C, D) or 0 in (A, B, C, D):
        arr.append(A)
        arr.append(B)
        arr.append(C)
        arr.append(D)
        break
    else:
        print("The switch status could be 1 or 0.")

print(arr)

sort(arr)


print('sorted arr:')
for i in range(len(arr)):
    print(arr[i], end=" ")
```

Comment: Can you correct the strings inside the while loop? It's not clear what is switch. Do you define it previously? If this is just a string, why have you wrapped the letters A,B,C, and D in quotes (e.g., 'A')?

Comment: yeah, sorry. it was in my motherlanguage and i edited i fast to english and i guess i missed them.

Comment: `[A, B, C, D] != 0 or [A, B, C, D] != 1` will never be true cause you're comparing lists to ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from random import randrange

def value_sum(dic):
    if sum(dic.values()) > 2:
        print("The lamp is on!")
    else:
        print("The lamp is off!")

dic={"A": None, "B": None, "C": None, "D": None}
question = input("Do you want to specify the order of switches and their state? (yes/no) ")

if question == "no":
    for i in dic.keys():
        dic[i] = randrange(2)
        print("{} is {}-{}".format(i, dic[i],"on" if dic[i] == 1 else "off"))
    value_sum(dic)

if question == "yes":
    sorrend = input("What should be the switches(A B C D) order: ")
    lista = sorrend.split()
    for i in lista:
        if i not in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'):
            print("Not corect switches: A B C D are the options")
            exit()
    print("Switches order is: ")
    print(lista)
    for i in lista:
        a = int(input("{} switch (1-on, 0-off): ".format(i)))
        if a in range(0,2):
            dic[i] = a
        else:
            print("The switch {} status should be 1-on or 0-off.".format(i))
            exit()
    value_sum(dic)

else:
    exit()
```

This is my solution. If the user uses to specify the switches state it takes the input from him. If not it will pick some random values. If 3 or 4 switches are up(1) it shows the message that lamp in on. You can take this and add some new functionalities if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, that I understand problem. I have not enough reputation to ask in comment.

First. You don't have initialize variables (`= int()`). Just set value (`= 0`) if you need a value.

Next. `[A, B, C, D] != 0` is always true. List is never equal to integer. `while True` is more readable.

I see you enter all four switches in ever step (that means you can switch on/off many switches at once). 
I don't know why you want to sort `arr`.

OK. First lets detect exactly 3 switches. I've shortened user input from 4 questions to one with all states (ex. `0 1 0 0`). I've skipped error detection (user have to enter 4 digits with spaces).

```py
switches = 'ABCD'
while True:
    state = input('Enter switches A, B, C, D: ').split()
    state = {switches[i] for i, v in enumerate(state) if v == '1'}
    on = len(state) == 3
    print('Lamp in {}'.format(['off', 'on'][on]))
```

Than try to add correct sequence.

```py
order = input('Enter switch order (ex. CAB): ')
order = [set(order[0:i+1]) for i in range(len(order))]
switches = 'ABCD'
states = []
while True:
    state = input('Enter switches A, B, C, D: ').split()
    state = set(switches[i] for i, v in enumerate(state) if v == '1')
    states.append(state)
    on = len(state) == 3 and (not order or order == states[-len(order):])
    print('Lamp is {}'.format(['off', 'on'][on]))
```

Now you can enter order `CAB` or empty string (no order). Then switch on one by one in order (or not if string was empty).

You can improve it by change 2nd line to

```py
order = [set(step) for step in order.split()]
```

and enter sequence of switches, ex. `C ABC`. Lamp will be on only if you switch on `C` and then both `A` and `B`.

You can add error detection (length of input), forgot very old states, and so on...